# database using arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

i want to know, can arcgis software do the database such as oracle or ms access?? for example, create own database and form?? and can the database in arcgis read the programmer program such as from matlab or visual basic. i want to create component maintenance in this software and the component link each other. but i want to use arcgis because i want to show database with the image when we click on the object. so, it is compatible to choose arcgis software to complete my project.

Answer (score 1):

For your project you can use the arcobject sdk an create your code in mxd (vba vb.net c#.net). If you have an sgbd install and matlab, import dlls you need to in the devlopment environnement.

Read this [article](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/85827-arcobject-sdk-vs-arcobject-runtime) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For the database, do you want to create the data in an external (Oracle or Access) database first and then import into ArcMap?

In ArcCatalog you can import (right click on dataset or gdb-->import feature class) and navigate to your Access or Oracle database.

If you're looking at editing database structure or making other changes to a geodatabase through Access or Oracle after it has been created DON'T! Lot's of dependencies that are happening behind the scenes and it's very easy to hose a database if you're not exactly sure what you're doing.